# getting a runtime error in the code

Tags: c, c99

GETTING A RUNTIME ERROR IN THE  given code

INITIALISING VARIABLES

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
int k;
int n;
int i;
int *a;
int b;
int t;
int f=0;
scanf("%d",&t);


while(t--){
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
```

dynami

```
    a=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",a[i]);
        a[i]=(k/a[i]);
    }
```

this is the point where the execution fails in runtime

```
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",b);
        a[i]=(a[i]*b);
```

finding the max element

```
        if(f==0){
            n=a[0];
            f=1;
        }
        if(a[i]>n)
            n=a[i];


    }//END FOR LOOP
    printf("%d\n",n);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n=a[0];` and `n=a[i];` Dangerous.

Comment: use other variable for maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
scanf("%d",b);
```

and

```
scanf("%d",a[i]);
```

to

```
scanf("%d",&b);
```

and

```
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
```

respectively and the code will work. `scanf` expects an argument of type `int*` but you provide an argument of type `int`. The `&` is the address-of operator and it gives the address of the variable,which in your case is an `int*` since both `a[i]` and `b` are `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%d",b);
```

should be :

```
scanf("%d",&b);
```

you miss a '&' that's why runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
scanf("%d",b);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d",&b);
```